# Hiding an object in Unity via SetActive()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity Engine 2019.3.9f1. Right now I'm trying to hide an object via SetActive(false), but perhaps I'm doing it incorrectly, or haven't anticipated something.

Right now I have a GameObject called 'TILE_LARGE_1' in the scene.

By pressing 'D' on the keyboard, I want to hide the object using SetActive(false). The script compiles fine, but the object isn't hidden when I press 'D'. Is there a caveat I'm unaware of using this method?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Utilities/VisObjects1")]
public class VisObjects1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject TILE_LARGE_1;

    void Start()
    {
        TILE_LARGE_1.SetActive(true); // false to hide, true to show
    }


   void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
         {

            TILE_LARGE_1.SetActive(false); // false to hide, true to show
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You put the code in the `Start` method, which is only called once at the beginning of the object's lifetime. You should instead put it in the `Update` method which is called every frame:

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        TILE_LARGE_1.SetActive(false); // false to hide, true to show
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh... I see. I've changed it, but now I seem to be getting a NullReferenceException error when I press 'D'. Am I missing something?It says:

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: `TILE_LARGE_1` was probably never set which is why it is null. You need to give it a value by either looking up the object in the `Start` method or by dragging a game object in your scene onto the component in the editor.

Comment: Hm, perhaps I've misunderstood. I updated the script above so you can see what I tried.

I've added a Start method, as you indicated, and set GameObject to active there, but I still seem to be getting the same error. Did I misinterpret?

Comment: You can't call anything on `TILE_LARGE_1` until it is set to reference an actual game object. You can't just add a `GameObject` field to your class and have Unity magically understand which game object you are wanting to work with.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that I dragged the script (VisObjects1) onto the 'TILE_LARGE_1' GameObject.

Comment: Seems to be working now. Thank you very much your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Abion47 pointed out, I hadn't indicated where/what the game object was. Solution as follows:

```
            GameObject TILE_LARGE_1 = GameObject.Find("TILE_LARGE_1");
            TILE_LARGE_1.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```